# Gradle place configuration file outside jar

Tags: java, gradle

I have a standard Spring Boot project.

I have a /src/main/resources folder where there are several configuration files.

I need these configuration files to live alongside the jar, NOT in the jar.

How can I achieve this with Gradle?

Answer (score -1):

this might helps [Repackage with custom Gradle configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-custom-configuration).
Use `exclude('**/*Something*')`

Comment: could you elaborate on this? where would the task run? that seems to be an exclude, but I also need the config files to accompany the jar, be in the build target directory.